# CSS absolute text on absolute image moves while resizing browser, why?

Tags: css, image, text, positioning

i've built a 3 column layout.
I want to place some Text (heading) over the Image in the middlecontent. But everytime i resize the browser window, the text moves. Any suggestions? I thought, while placing the image in an absolute container (which is itself in an relative one) i can position any absolute layers without the elements moving. Any suggestions?

Here a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dkjsc/3/

**UPDATE:**
If we remove the height attribute from middlecontent, everything works fine. But is this a way to go?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content" class="content">

  <!--LEFT-->
   <div id="leftcontent" class="leftcontent">&nbsp;</div>

  <!--MIDDLE-->
  <div id="middlecontent" class="middlecontent">
     <div id="heading" class="heading">Text</div>
     <img src="images/Windows/Window_10.png" alt="" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <!--RIGHT-->
  <div id="rightcontent" class="rightcontent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.content {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.leftcontent{
 position:absolute;
 width:20%;
 height:100%;
 left:0%;
}

.middlecontent {
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 width:60%;
 height:100%;
 left:20%;
 top:10%;
 }

.rightcontent {
 position:absolute;
 width:20%;
 height:100%;
 right:0%;
}

.heading{
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 top:12%;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dkjsc/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put position relative on an element with a fixed size that you want it relative of otherwise it is relative to the window which keeps changing size

Comment: But i need to have the size in percentage for a responsive behave on resizing. Isn't that possible with my code?

Comment: Please can you give me a fiddle so I can check it out